# Trying to attach to my windows service but shows as disabled in available processes

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I'm trying to attach to a windows service I am running to debug it however the "Available Processes" list under "Attach to Process" it shows as disabled and won't allow me to attach.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/620660-trouble-attaching-windows-service-process

Apparently the dialog doesn't display all services running by default and there is an instance of [MyServiceName].vshost.exe running that had me confused.  Simply clicking the filter to display all services revealed my "hidden" service.